# In python how can I copy a data from an excel to a web site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm not a programmer but am trying to use python to build a program that will;
1- copy data from an excel sheet, paste it to a web site search screen. 
after submitting the search;
2- use additional data on the same excel to submit an rfq for that specific data.
the excel will contain these details; column A = rfq ref, column B = pn details, column C = quantity required, column D = priority of the requirement.

the program should first search for a pn on column B (say B1) on the web site, then after getting the results, should use column A, B, C, D data (A1, B1, C1, D1) to submit a detailed search for that pn. 
then program should go back to the first search page and do the same thing for the 2nd row (B2) etc...

here's what I've written so far;

```
import pyautogui
import pandas as pdd
import time


pyautogui.click(321, 51)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.press('del')
pyautogui.typewrite('https://www.whatever.com/')
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.press('tab', interval=0.2)

df = pdd.read_excel("search.xlsx", header=None)
rfq=(df[0].tolist())
pn=(df[1].tolist())
qty=(df[2].tolist())
priority=(df[3].tolist())
note=(df[4].tolist())

for i in range(len(pn)):
  pyautogui.typewrite(str(pn[i]), interval=1);
  pyautogui.press('enter')
```

(I have not written the second part of the code where I'll submit the detailed rfq using A1, B1, C1, D1 data)

the problem with the code is;
1- with this for loop the program gets all the B1, B2, B3, B4... etc all at once copies it one after another to the search part. how can I resolve this?
2- say if I succeed in submitting the first search (B1), how can I tell the program to search for B2 now?

I'm a total newbie, so sorry for taking your time, and I really appreciate your detailed explanations and if possible examples of similiar codes.

thanks.
turker

Comment: That's __way__ too broad...

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

First, it might help to create a function for completing your task, and then looping over it:

```
def submit_rqf(row):
    pyautogui.click(321, 51)
    etc...
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(row[1]), interval=1)

for i in df.index:
    submit_rqf(df.loc[i])
```

This way, you also don't need to make lists out of every column in the dataframe and are using them directly.

I suspect you will have to figure out how long the original search takes, so your code will look something like:

```
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.typewrite(str(row[1]), interval=1)
time.sleep(X)
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.typewrite(str(row[2]))
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.typewrite(str(row[3]))
```

That's: original search, wait for page to load, add additional information.

A few things that may also help: you can run the process in a new tab once you're done with a previous one, to make sure it has time to finish processing. You can also try to detect an image on the page that signifies the form is done running, with [pyautogui.locateOnScreen](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions). Take that image as a screenshot, then do something like:

```
while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('snipped_image.PNG') is None:
    time.sleep(1)
```

This basically says: check if you see this image on my screen - if not, wait a sec and try again.

So your final loop looks something like:

```
for i in df.index:
    submit_rqf(df.loc[i])
    while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('snipped_image.PNG') is None:
        time.sleep(1)
```

You can also use pyautogui.locateOnScreen to see if your original search is done and you can start adding the extra fields. I hope this helps!